# The palatino font does not allow for the mathtypesetting

Tags: math-mode, mathpazo

I use TeXlive with TeXMaker on a Debian system. The palatino font does not allow for the mathematics type setting. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font

\begin{document}
$A$
\end{document}
```

The error is the following.

```
! pdfTeX error (vf): unexpected EOF or error.
<to be read again>
\endgroup \set@typeset@protect
l.10 \end{document}
...
(etc,etc)
...
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This code compiles fine with " lmodern " in place of " mathpazo ".

How does math-mode work with Palatino?

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me.  You might want to make sure to delete intermediate files (e.g., `.aux`) and recompile.

Comment: TeXlive with MiKTeX? Besides it sounds as if a vf-file is broken.

Comment: I meant TeXMaker instead of MikTeX.

Comment: No, deleting any intermediate files does not help.

Comment: What is a vf file, @Ulrike? Can you help me replace it?

Comment: One of the font files is broken. Try reinstalling `texlive-latex-base` with `apt-get`